# Hibernate Search 6: Trying to sort dynamic fields with field templates leads to error 'unknown field'

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm trying to switch from Hibernate 5 to Hibernate 6 with Elasticsearch backend.
In our project there is an entity with dynamic number of fields. As I understand it the best way to handle this would be to use dynamic fields with templates as described here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#bridge-index-field-dsl-dynamic

I created a property binder to add the dynamic fields to the index. This works well, the fields are added to the index and can be searched. The problem is now how can I sort this fields? I'm getting the error: org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH000610: Unknown field 'customFields.town_TextForSort.keyword'.

The property binder contains the following code:

```
public class AddressElementBinder implements PropertyBinder {

    @Override
    public void bind(PropertyBindingContext context) {
        context
            .dependencies()
            .useRootOnly();

        IndexSchemaElement schemaElement = context.indexSchemaElement();
        
        IndexSchemaObjectField customFields = schemaElement
                .objectField( "customFields", ObjectStructure.FLATTENED)
                .multiValued();

        customFields.fieldTemplate( 
                "fieldValueTemplate_TextDefault", 
                f -> f.asString()
                .analyzer("customAnalyzer")
                .searchable( Searchable.YES )
                .sortable(Sortable.NO)
        )
        .matchingPathGlob( "*_TextDefault" );

        customFields.fieldTemplate( 
                "fieldValueTemplate_TextForSort",
                f -> f.asString()
                .normalizer("customNormalizer")
                .sortable( Sortable.YES )
                .searchable( Searchable.NO )
        )
        .matchingPathGlob( "*_TextForSort" );

        context.bridge( Set.class, new AddressElementBridge(customFields.toReference()) ); 
    }
}
```

The property bridge:

```
public class AddressElementBridge implements PropertyBridge<Set> {

    private IndexObjectFieldReference customFieldFieldReference = null;
    
    public AddressElementBridge(IndexObjectFieldReference customFieldFieldReference) {
        this.customFieldFieldReference = customFieldFieldReference;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void write(DocumentElement target, Set bridgedElement, PropertyBridgeWriteContext context) {
        if(bridgedElement == null || bridgedElement.isEmpty() || this.customFieldFieldReference == null) {
            return;
        }
                                                
        DocumentElement customFieldElement = target.addObject( this.customFieldFieldReference ); 
                
        AbstractPostalAddress postalAddress = ContactAddressHelper.getMainPostalAddress(bridgedElement);        
        List<CustomField> fields = postalAddress.getFields(context);
        if(fields == null ||  fields.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        
        for (FieldInfoFullTextIndex customField : fields) {
            
            String fieldName = customField.getFieldName();
            Object fieldValue = customField.getFieldValue();
            
            if(fieldValue != null) {
                                
                if(fieldValue instanceof String) {          
                    
                    fieldName = fieldName + "_TextDefault";
                    customFieldElement.addValue( fieldName, fieldValue );

                    fieldName = fieldName + "_TextForSort";
                    customFieldElement.addValue( fieldName, fieldValue );
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
```

The new fields are added to the index like this:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "_source": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "_entity_type": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": false
                },
                "customFields": {
                    "dynamic": "true",
                    "properties": {
                        "town_TextDefault": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "town_TextForSort": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Analyzer and normalizer definition:

```
public class GlobalElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurer implements ElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(ElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurationContext context) {
    
        context.analyzer( "customAnalyzer" )
            .custom()
            .tokenizer( "standard" ) 
            .charFilters( "html_strip" ) 
            .tokenFilters( "lowercase", "asciifolding" );

        context.normalizer( "customNormalizer" )
            .custom() 
            .tokenFilters( "lowercase", "asciifolding" );

    }
}
```

Using path "customFields.town_TextForSort" for sorting is not a good idea because it is of type "text" and not "keyword".
Using path "customFields.town_TextForSort.keyword" for sorting does not work because of the error: HSEARCH000610: Unknown field 'customFields.town_TextForSort.keyword'.

if a run a search using the Elasticsearch interface directly with path "customFields.town_TextForSort.keyword", then it works. Elasticsearch returns a sorted result.

Is this is a bug in Hibernate Search 6? Because the field validation fails (Hibernate Search does not know about the sub field "keyword".
Or is my setup wrong? I assumed that the fields would be all of type keyword and not text if ObjectStructure.FLATTENED is used.
Or is Elasticsearch creating a keyword sub field? How can I force the fields to be of type keyword instead of text?

Update 2023-03-22: I updated the code blocks above.

Answer (score 0):

First, Hibernate Search does not support multi-fields yet (see [HSEARCH-3465](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3465)), so this `.keyword` sub-field is not something it can work with.

Second, even if it did, that `.keyword` subfield you see in your Elasticsearch schema is never mentioned in the field definition on the Hibernate Search side: it's added automatically by Elasticsearch because of some default template on the server side. So Hibernate Search wouldn't know about this subfield.

The solution would be for you to add a sibling field instead of relying on multi-fields. And that's what you apparently tried to do... but somehow the Elasticsearch schema doesn't match what you configured on the Hibernate Search side:

1. I don't see "customFields" mentioned anywhere in your Elasticsearch schema.
2. I don't see your custom analyzer and normalizer mentioned anywhere in your Elasticsearch schema.

So there's something wrong.

I think you either:

1. Forgot to [have Hibernate Search create the Elasticsearch schema](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-schema-management) before performing your tests.
2. Forgot to [create the `customFields` object field in your bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-index-field-dsl-object) (e.g. `DocumentElement customFields = target.addObject("customFields")`
3. Mistakenly added the value of `fieldValueTemplate_TextDefault`/`fieldValueTemplate_TextForSort` to the root (the `target` parameter passed to your field) instead of adding them to your `customFields` object field.

I'd need the full code of your binder/bridge and your full Elasticsearch schema to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the code to clarify things. The schema is created with Hibernate Search during application start and I deleted it before the tests.  I didn't change anything in Elasticsearch directly. Except the multiValued setting, I cannot find the problem.

Comment: Your Elasticsearch mapping doesn't include the dynamic mapping templates you defined in Hibernate Search; if that was working there would be a `dynamic_templates` section somewhere. Are you sure you had Hibernate Search create the Elasticsearch mapping?

Comment: If you're sure, I'll need a reproducer. You can base it on https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/main/search/hibernate-search-6/orm-elasticsearch .

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the dynamic_templates section. That was actually missing. I figured out what went wrong: I used a custom schema_management.mapping_file with {
  "_source": {
    "enabled": false
  }
}  to reduce the size of Elasticsearch indexes.  Using this mapping file seems to cause the problem. The value for 'enabled' does not matter.